# Install multiple packages via bash script with dnf

Tags: bash, command

I'm currently writing a bash script which should install all the software that I need. The process looks promising so far: First, I write a "software-list.txt" file which contains all dependencies for multiple distros. Afterwards bash split these values into an array and reads the corresponding value out of it. Finally the script should combine the distro package manager name (e.g. dnf, if I'm using Fedora Linux) with the operator ("install") with the arguments (which are the software packages).One last info: All variable names which don't appear in the source code, we're defined beforehand
The script looks like this:

One last info: All variable names which don't appear in the source code, were defined beforehand

```
case "$DISTRO_NAME" in
    "Fedora")
            PROGRAMM="dnf"
            CSV_INDEX=0;;
    "Debian")
            PROGRAMM="apt-get"
            CSV_INDEX=1;;
esac

# Read all required packages
while IFS= read -r line
do
    IFS=','
    LINE=($line)
    if [ $CURR_LINE_INDEX -gt 1 ] && [ $CURR_LINE_INDEX -lt $LINE_COUNT ]
    then
            ARGUMENTS+="${LINE[$CSV_INDEX]} "
    elif [ $CURR_LINE_INDEX -eq $LINE_COUNT ]
    then
            ARGUMENTS+="${LINE[$CSV_INDEX]}"
    fi
    CURR_LINE_INDEX=$((CURR_LINE_INDEX+1))
done  < "software-list.txt"

# Run installation script
$PROGRAMM $OPERATOR $ARGUMENTS
```

However, whenever I run the script, the command is correct. But the output is always the same "couldn't find any match for packagex packagey"

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation. Also the OLD_IFS trick is a sign that you're doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I followed [Jetchisel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4452265/jetchisel)'s advice and did a shellcheck. How is it now?

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$DISTRO_NAME" in
    "Fedora")
            PROGRAMM="dnf"
            CSV_INDEX=0;;
    "Debian")
            PROGRAMM="apt-get"
            CSV_INDEX=1;;
esac

# Read all required packages
while IFS= read -r -a line
do
    IFS=','
    LINE=("${line[@]}")
    if [ "$CURR_LINE_INDEX" -gt 1 ] && [ "$CURR_LINE_INDEX" -lt "$LINE_COUNT" ]
    then
            ARGUMENTS+="${LINE[$CSV_INDEX]} "
    elif [ "$CURR_LINE_INDEX" -eq "$LINE_COUNT" ]
    then
            ARGUMENTS+="${LINE[$CSV_INDEX]}"
    fi
    CURR_LINE_INDEX=$((CURR_LINE_INDEX+1))
done  < "software-list.txt"

# Run installation script
"$PROGRAMM $OPERATOR $ARGUMENTS"
```